# wording in a legal document made in an Employment Tribunal in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, legal-terms

In a legal document, pertaining to an Employment Tribunal held in the UK, what does the following statement mean:

"Save as expressly admitted or denied above, no admissions are made as to any part of the Claimant's claim."

It sounds to me that the solicitor is saying that "even if we missed something out in our denials, then we deny it"?

Or does it mean "we are saying nothing about any claims made if we did not notice that claim"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally that they only admit or deny the claim(s) they explicitly stated they admit or deny, they do not admit to anything else by implication or inference.